# Multiline UILabel not wrapping words correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uilabel

I am having a problem resizing the font size to fit a label and not splitting any words.
 I have a label that will change its content dynamically based on an array of strings.
 The label could have any number of lines. What I want is for the font size to be as big as possible while fitting the label AND not splitting any words.
 I made the font size very big on storyboard.
 The label is placed on the view using Auto-Layout.

For example for a string "Most definitely" if I use this code:

```
 answerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
 answerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
 answerLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

I get strings like:
Most(line 1)
Definitel(line 2) y(line 3)

If on the other hand I do

```
    answerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    answerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    answerLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

I get a string "Mo" in big letters

Obviously what I am looking for in that case is Most(line 1) definitely(line 2).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: how are your constraints in your label?

Comment: The label is on top of an UiImageView so the label constraints are align X and Y to image and proportional width and height to image.

Comment: The problem is with the height, take it off

Comment: The solutions there are great. Used them myself

Comment: Did you manage to solve this @JPAquino?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

Set number of lines zero for dynamic text information, it will be useful for varying text.

```
var label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "Multiline UILabel not wrapping words correctly"
label.text = stringValue
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail // or .byWrappingWord
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8 . // It is not required but nice to have a minimum scale factor to fit text into label frame
```

**Using Interface Builder:**

[image]

Comment: This works for the "Most definitely" string but don't work for others. It still causes the words to be split.

Comment: Please share your exact query, what are other words, and what's your design, so I can provide you solution accordingly...